# AJAX getting data from XML and place it in a <ul>

Tags: ajax, xml

I am new to AJAX and trying to build a dropdown-meny from a XML-file.
With my example I'm only getting "Akershus" to post in the menu.
Can anyone help me with this?
Best regards, a student from Norway.

Here is the XML:

```
<arrangement>
   <fylke name="Akershus">
   <fylke name="Buskerud">
   <fylke name="Hordaland">
   <fylke name="Nordland">
</arrangement>
```

Here is the script:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
arrangementer();
fetch();
});

/*function fetch() {

setTimeout( function() {
    arrangementer();
    fetch();
}, 100);

}*/

function arrangementer() {

$.ajax({ 

    url: "arrangementer.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(data) {

        $('ul').children().remove();

        $(data).find("arrangement").each( function() {

            var info = '<a href="#">'+$(this).find("fylke").attr("name")+'</a>';

            $('ul').append(info);

        });

    },
    error: function() { $('ul').children().remove(); 
        $('ul').append("<li>There was an error!</li>"); }
   });  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
$(data).find("arrangement").each
```

use

```
$(data).find("arrangement fylke").each
```

And remove `.find("fylke")`.

Or you could do this even more succinctly (and with proper escaping),

```
$(data).find('arrangement fylke').map(function() {
    return $('<a href="#"></a>').text($(this).attr('name'));
}).appendTo('ul');
```

Comment: Great! If this was the answer you were looking for, click the green checkmark to the left. It will mark this answer as accepted.